# Google WindowBuilder for Java

Tags: java

I made a GUI in Eclipse using the Google WindowBuilder plugin. The problem is that when I right-click on the design representation of my code and click, "Test/Preview," my GUI works and looks perfectly (the picture on the right), but when I click the "run" button in Eclipse to actually run the code, the GUI looks all weird (the picture on the left).

Does anybody have a clue as to what the problem is?

[image: Here is the comparison picture]

Answer (score 2):

Ok this could have multiple reasons, the most obvious one being, that you (accidentally?) set your JButtons' background Color to the same dark-gray as your Frame's background. Check This first! WindowBuilder's preview has a quirk of sometimes not showing recent design changes on some elements immediately.

If that Is not the case with you, it might be some weird formatting thing. 
Have you manually changed your buttons' formatting within the code and not within the design tab? Then add (Say your button is called okButton) `okButton.repaint();` after the changes you manually made.

If this still doesnt work, 
Try adding `okButton.setVisible(true);` (Althought that is pretty far fetched, seeing that a button outline can be seen!)